# How to change the value of an html text field from its default value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, struts

I'm using struts 1.2 with angular js to send a jsp form, I am having problems setting the value of an input field. Here's the javascript code to set the default value of the field "city" that comes from the server into the jsp when the page loads, this is because i cannot use the html struts tag to pre-populated because it does not support the angularjs attributes i need to use in the input field:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var defaultCity = $("[name='city']").val();
    $('#city').val(defaultCity);
});
</script>
```

here's the jsp section:

```
<body ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<form name = "LocationForm" method="POST" action="someaction.do">
 <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' >

                            <div class="section">
                                <label class="field prepend-icon">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"  id="city" class="gui-input" placeholder="City">
                                    <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                    <html:hidden property="city"/>
                                </label>
                            </div><!-- end section -->
    </div>
......
</form>
```

The problem with this is that once i input something in that field to override what's pre-populated, the text doesn't take, the struts action gets the original value the page loaded with only. So i tried to add the following in the jsp to see if at the time of submitting the form, the value can be changed, here's the code:

```
    //Needed to override load value at submition time
$("[name='LocationForm']").submit(function(e) {
    var cityValue= $("[name='city']").val();
    $('#city').val(cityValue);
});
```

However it didn't work either, debugging into it would still return the original value even though i can see in the browser the new value i typed.

If on the other hand, i remove all the javascripts, then the jsp will send the newly typed value, however, it won't set the default value of the field at load time, i need both things to happen, load the default value and if i type something different in the input field, then the new value should be submitted.

Can someone please tell me what am i missing to be able to submit whatever is typed on the field on submission and not have always the default value sent over?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, apparently the problem was the binding, i put the submit function of the javascript code at the bottom of the page and it picked it up.